# Exploding lines with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, line, linestring, vertices, explode

Are there ways to realize exploding lines through PyQGIS?

I have layer with very complicated line and exploding lines is so slow, it doesn't end even after an hour. I've created spatial index and run it multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume there is a polyline layer called *'to_explode'* (three features) with its attribute tables, see the image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below:

```
# imports
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer, QgsPointXY, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry)

# getting original line layer by its name
lines = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LINE_LAYER_NAME')[0]

# creating a polyline layer for the output
result = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={lines.crs().authid()}&index=yes", "exploded_lines", "memory")

# accessing resulting layer's provider
provider = result.dataProvider()
# nesting original attributes into the output layer
provider.addAttributes(lines.fields())
result.updateFields()

# looping over each original feature
for feat in lines.getFeatures():
    # accessing feature's vertices
    vertices = [QgsPointXY(vertex) for vertex in feat.geometry().vertices()]
    # making pairs of points for the output
    for pair in list(zip(vertices, vertices[1:])):
        # creating a new feature
        new_feat = QgsFeature()
        # providing new geometry for the new feature
        new_geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(pair)
        new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
        # setting original attributes
        new_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
        # adding the feature
        provider.addFeature(new_feat)

# adding output layer to the canvas
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result)
```

Change the input layer name `'LINE_LAYER_NAME'`, press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like this:

[image: result]